# C# .Net MysqlConnector ConnectionString Password Problem / Issue

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

need help with some stupid password problems. Following problem:

Cannot connect to mysql server with some passwords ^^

If i use a password with the same "connection string" details, for example:

The following Passwords are exactly in the MySql Server (quotes, double-quotes, semicolon);

"pwd=123456";    // works

"pwd=123456;";   // works

";pwd=123;456;'  // System.ArgumentException

";pwd=123;456;'" // System.ArgumentException

```
//Connection String Variant 1:

string connString = string.Format("server={0};port={1};uid={2};pwd={3};database={4};sslmode=preferred",
                tbDbServername.Text.ToLower(),
                (uint)Convert.ToInt32(tbDbServerPort.Text),
                tbDbServerUsername.Text.ToLower(),
                tbDbServerPassword.Password,
                tbDbServerDatabase.Text.ToLower()
                );

//Connection String Variant 2:

string connString = string.Format("server={0};port={1};uid={2};pwd='{3}';database={4};sslmode=preferred",
                tbDbServername.Text.ToLower(),
                (uint)Convert.ToInt32(tbDbServerPort.Text),
                tbDbServerUsername.Text.ToLower(),
                tbDbServerPassword.Password,
                tbDbServerDatabase.Text.ToLower()
                );
```

I know it's stupid. Why should someone use a password with connection string details....but would be nice to solve this.

Greetings from Germany :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to construct your connection string.  It will do any escaping/quoting that's needed.

In your case, you would want to do this:

```cs
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    Server = tbDbServername.Text.ToLower(),
    Port = (uint)System.Convert.ToInt32(tbDbServerPort.Text),
    UserID = tbDbServerUsername.Text.ToLower(),
    Password = tbDbServerPassword.Password,
    Database = tbDbServerDatabase.Text.ToLower(),
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Preferred
};

string connString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Too easy. Thank you very much. Works :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters are not allowed in `connection string` like `[] {}() , ; ? * ! @ =.` **without using `escape-character`**. The use of `;` as part of password has caused problem as its expected to be used as `delimiter`

The special notes on special characters is mentioned at relatively odd place in Microsoft documentation:

[Notes on special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/strong-passwords?view=sql-server-ver15)

> If used in an OLE DB or ODBC connection string, a login or password
>   must not contain the following characters: [] {}() , ; ? * ! @ =.
>   These characters are used to either initialize a connection or
>   separate connection values.

[ConnectionString](http://The%20basic%20format%20of%20a%20connection%20string%20includes%20a%20series%20of%20keyword/value%20pairs%20separated%20by%20semicolons.%20The%20equal%20sign%20(=)%20connects%20each%20keyword%20and%20its%20value.%20To%20include%20values%20that%20contain%20a%20semicolon,%20single-quote%20character,%20or%20double-quote%20character,%20the%20value%20must%20be%20enclosed%20in%20double%20quotation%20marks.%20If%20the%20value%20contains%20both%20a%20semicolon%20and%20a%20double-quote%20character,%20the%20value%20can%20be%20enclosed%20in%20single%20quotation%20marks.%20The%20single%20quotation%20mark%20is%20also%20useful%20if%20the%20value%20starts%20with%20a%20double-quote%20character.%20Conversely,%20the%20double%20quotation%20mark%20can%20be%20used%20if%20the%20value%20starts%20with%20a%20single%20quotation%20mark.%20If%20the%20value%20contains%20both%20single-quote%20and%20double-quote%20characters,%20the%20quotation%20mark%20character%20used%20to%20enclose%20the%20value%20must%20be%20doubled%20every%20time%20it%20occurs%20within%20the%20value.)

> The basic format of a connection string includes a series of
>   keyword/value pairs separated by semicolons. The equal sign (=)
>   connects each keyword and its value. To include values that contain a
>   **semicolon**, **single-quote** character, or double-quote character, the
>   value must be ***enclosed in double quotation marks***. If the value
>   contains both a semicolon and a double-quote character, the value can
>   be enclosed in single quotation marks. The single quotation mark is
>   also useful if the value starts with a double-quote character.
>   Conversely, the double quotation mark can be used if the value starts
>   with a single quotation mark. If the value contains both single-quote
>   and double-quote characters, the quotation mark character used to
>   enclose the value must be doubled every time it occurs within the
>   value.

Comment: @Thomas A worth reading for connection string formatr `MySQL` at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html.  Please note that when we connect from C# assembly then it connects via `MySQL/ODBC` connector.

Comment: All those characters can be used in MySQL user passwords, and can be used in a MySQL connection string if escaped properly (use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to do this).

Comment: @bradleyGraingrr I agree it can be used with proper escape character and it's mention in link with my answer too. I don't understand why confusion came?

Comment: Your answer states in its first sentence: "Certain characters are not allowed in `connection string` like `[] {}() , ; ? * ! @ =.`". This is not true for MySQL, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I meant without escape character or other formats. I over looked as it was mentioned in link. Moreover the second link for specifically `MySQL` it's states that for `MySQL` connection string can `URI-like connection strings or key-value pairs`. But point is when connection string is used via `MySQL/ODBC` connectors those characters are not allowed without escape-characters.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer to avoid confusion.